# self referencing to parent object if it has child object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-reference

I am working on my **rails api**.
It has a model location. Now, cities can have muliple names. Like "Bangalore"(parent object) and "Bangaluru"(child object). Model is self referencing. I want to add a constraint to prevent my users from refering to child object. They should refer to parent object always.

**Here's my code:**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location # i.e. may have a parent location
  has_many :users,  dependent: :restrict_with_error
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  before_save :lowercase_name
  auto_strip_attributes :name, squish: true, nullify: false

  enum status: [
       :invisible, # default
       :major, # a major city
       :minor, # a minor city
       :child, # i.e. it has a parent that should be used instead
   ]
end
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you give an example where user would refer to a child object?

Comment: No . user always has to refer to parent object. Like if user refers to Bangalore(child object) than a constraint has to be provided so that user refers to "bangaluru"(parent object)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a `parent_id` field in your `locations` table, you can do something like this

```
belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

Now, `user.location.parent_location` will give you the parent location, or you can do

```
location = user.location
location = location.parent_location_present? ? location.parent_location : location
```

in location model,

```
def parent_location_present?
  parent_location.present?
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I dont have a parent_id . Location is self referencing to itself. It has enum as shown above. i just need to write a custom validator.  def child_location_not_present
    return false if location.child.present?
  end. But its not working. how to check whether  child object is present or not?

Comment: How will you get location.child? You need to have a parent id column to achieve this